# Angular ng serve asking to open app and not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, angular-cli

**Problem Statement**

When I try to do `ng s -o` in my terminal for my Angular app, it says, "How would you like to open this?" inside a popup box where I can choose an app, but choosing an app doesn't work.

---

**Image of Problem**

When I try to choose an app, it displays code. When I chose Chrome in the popup box, this happens:

[image]

The image shows that when I run an app after `ng s -o` it just displays code. Also, the tab title in the browser says "*ng*" when the code shows. Another thing, there is no error in the terminal...

---

**Expected Results**

I want to run my Angular app with `ng s -o`.

---

**Actual Results**

The app doesn't serve and asks to open an app.

---

**Note:** I am using Visual Studio Code for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was related to my cli. I was using PowerShell when I was running `ng`, and for some strange reason, PowerShell stopped running `ng` and was asking me to open an app to run the file. Even though this never happened to me before and I was using `ng` and PowerShell just fine before. Strange!

Now I am using CMD instead. It now runs perfectly. So, I switched cli's from PowerShell to CMD in my integrated terminal in Visual Studio Code and it started working.

I got the idea to switch cli's from this: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/28541

Comment: Try "npx ng serve -o". It will work in VSC.

Answer (score 2):

`npx ng serve -o` works for me in visual studio code.

[image: Refer the screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused as the Vs code was using PowerShell mode. By changing it to default cmd mode, the ng commands started to work.
The steps to change from PowerShell to cmd mode is as follows:

1. Press Ctrl + Shift + P to show all commands.
2. Type profile in the displayed text box to filter the list.
3. Select Terminal: Select Default Profile.
4. You will be prompted to select your preferred terminal shell, you can change this later in your settings or follow the same process as we do now.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command as tentative solution, it will work `npm run ng serve`